# Object recognition with Kinect

Tags: opencv, kinect, point-cloud-library, object-recognition

I'm trying to recognize rectangular boxes using Kinect, I know I can use OpenCV or PCL to do this but my C++ is a bit rusty, I'm new to Computer Vision in 3D and I want to do it as quick as possible, it's only a demo for a bigger project.

Is there anyway to do it using C# or at least Python, I don't care if I have to learn 3D.

If not, which library should I use, OpenCV or PCL?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do, and on what platform?

Comment: Right now the demo has to recognize a box, I thought of a depth map and then coloring only the box, leaving everything else in a gray scale.

I tried to do it with the SDK for Windows, and I'd like to stay in Windows if possible.

Comment: You can use the official SDK to access the Kinect hardware, but there are no built-in abilities for doing what you seek.  As @Sacx mentions below, OpenCV can help with some of the leg work (passing it the image data obtained by the SDK).  There are C# wrappers that will let you stay in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend OpenCV.

If you want to work in C# or python with OpenCV then you have wrappers for both of them:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/getting-started-with-python-a-opencv

Comment: There are also multiple existing examples of using Kinect and OpenCV together to do many different things.  OpenCV will likely do what you want, but will certainly give you a good introduction if it somehow comes up short.